# what formula should I use to found the sum of $Σ_{ k = 2 }^{ 6 } ( { k }^{ 2 } -7) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Today I am trying to solve this question, and it asks me to **found the sum**.
$$Σ_{ k =  2  }^{ 6  } ( { k  }^{ 2  }  -7) $$

---

I tried to found a formula to solve this, but I could not found it. In this case, I typed the question into [Microsoft Math Solver](https://mathsolver.microsoft.com/en/solve-problem/%60displaystyle%60sum_%7B%20k%20%3D%20%202%20%20%7D%5E%7B%206%20%20%7D%20%60left(%20%7B%20k%20%20%7D%5E%7B%202%20%20%7D%20%20-7%20%60right)), but it only show me the answer so I could not get the formula. I also tried to search the internet but I can not found one.

---

I am wondering what kind of sequences this is, and what equation should I use to found the sum
And I do not want to plug in each number because next time it may be:
$$Σ_{ k =  2  }^{ 99  } ( { k  }^{ 2  }  -7) $$

Comment: Did you try plugging in $k=2,3,4,5,6$ and adding the five terms?

Comment: $Σ_{ k =  1 }^{ n  }  { k  }^{ 2  }=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6 $

Comment: This is a sum of five numbers. You can brute force it with paper and pencil in under a minute. If the upper bound for $k$ were left undetermined $\sum_{k=2}^n$, or a lot higher $\sum_{k=2}^{213}$, then you need a formula.  A useful formula exists for the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$, did you search?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Is there are any formulars to do that?

Comment: @HanHan The above comments address your updated question

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I want to search but I do not know what's that sequence called, so what I found is all about something else.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Could you explain why it is 6 at the bottom?

Comment: @HanHan You can prove that formula by induction (and many other ways).  See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Sequence_of_Squares).

Comment: See also [Faulhaber formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

Comment: Typing in *sum of consecutive squares* to Google gave me a lot of hits. Of varying quality and relevance, but there were good ones among them. To search on this site you can also try and put the TeXified formula into [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5Enk%5E2%24&p=1). Admittedly there was no reason for you to be familiar with the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=2}^n k^2-7 = (\sum_{k=1}^n k^2-7) - (1^2-7)$$
Also
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2-7 = (\sum_{k=1}^n k^2)-(\sum_{k=1}^n 7) $$
There is a formula which states that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}$$
Also you get
$$\sum_{k=1}^n 7 = 7n$$
Plug the values in the original equation and you get
$$\sum_{k=2}^6 k^2-7 = 91-42+6=55$$

Answer (score 1):

First utilize $$\sum_{k=1}^bc=bc$$So that your sum becomes $$\sum_{k=2}^6k^2-35$$Then use $$\sum_{k=2}^bk^2=\frac{b(b+1)(2b+1)}6-1$$So the answer is $90-35=55$.

But before you leave, upvote this answer. It makes both of us happy.

Comment: Thanks for answering, and I can not understand what is c in the first equation, because I do not know that formular, could you explain what is c, or giving me the name of the formular?

Comment: Hello @HanHan. This $c$ is some number, like $7$ in your case.